# Python Selector with FIFO running to infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, select, kqueue

I am trying to write some non-blocking FIFO code with kqueue on my BSD machine. Here's the small server code: `server.py`

```
import os
import selectors

sel = selectors.KqueueSelector()

TMP_PATH="/tmp/myfifo"

def fifo_read(fd, mask):
    data = os.read(fd, 8)
    print("fd:{} gives:{} \n", fd, data)
    sel.unregister(fd)
    print("unregistered")

def fifo_accept(listen_fd, mask):
    print("accepted {}".format(listen_fd))
    fd = os.dup(listen_fd)
    print("duped to {}".format(fd))
    sel.register(fd, selectors.EVENT_READ, fifo_read)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        os.unlink(TMP_PATH)
    except:
        pass

    os.mkfifo(TMP_PATH)
    listen_fd = os.open(TMP_PATH, os.O_RDONLY, mode=0o600)

    sel.register(listen_fd, selectors.EVENT_READ, fifo_accept)

    while True:
        events = sel.select()
        for key, mask in events:
            cb = key.data
            cb(key.fileobj, mask)

    sel.close()
```

Now, when I run a `client.py` as:

```
import os

TMP_PATH="/tmp/myfifo"

fd = os.open(TMP_PATH, os.O_WRONLY, mode=0o600)

res = os.write(fd, b"1234567")

print("sent {}".format(res))
```

When I run the client, I get:
`sent 7`

But on server, it runs to inifinite loop. Now I understand why the infinite loop is happening. I actually tried mimicking the socket way of using `selectors` in this [Python Docs example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#examples).
Here's what I have tried:

- I did try the code without duplicating the `fd`, but it's still in infinite loop.
- I tried calling `sel.unregister` on the original `listen_fd`, but in this case, running the client the second time doesn't work (which is expected).

Can anyone please let me know if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So I found one solution to this problem. With sockets, we get a new socket object on accept. So we need to emulate that behaviour by calling `unregister` on the original `fileobj`, `open` again and call `register` on that.

Fixed code:

```
import os
import selectors

sel = selectors.KqueueSelector()

try:
    os.unlink("./myfifo")
except:
    pass
os.mkfifo("./myfifo", 0o600)


def cb(fp):
    sel.unregister(fp)
    print(f"got {fp.read()}")
    fp.close()
    fp2 = open("./myfifo", "rb")
    sel.register(fp2, selectors.EVENT_READ, cb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    orig_fp = open("./myfifo", "rb")
    print("open done")
    ev = sel.register(orig_fp, selectors.EVENT_READ, cb)
    print(f"registration done for {ev}")

    while True:
        events = sel.select()
        print(events)
        for key, mask in events:
            key.data(key.fileobj)
```